# Prove a semi-positive operator $T$ is an isometry if and only if $T$ is the identity operator.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove a semi-positive operator $T$ is an isometry if and only if $T$ is the identity operator.

I was thinking that semi-positive means if $T$ is self-adjoint ($T^{*}=T$) and $\langle T(u),u\rangle \geq 0$ for all $u \in V$.

Isometry if and only if $T^{*}T=I_{v}$ if an only if $TT^{*}=I_{v}$

any idea how would I get started

Comment: Are you assuming the Hilbert space to be finitely dimensional?

Comment: Assuming $T=I$ we can see that $T=T^{-1}$, and because $T$ is self adjoint we can see that $T=T^*$. So we have: $I=TT^{-1}=T^2=TT=TT^*=T^*T$ and so $T$ is an isometry. I'll leave it to you to try the other direction.

Comment: the only thing that my book mentioned that a semi-postive Hermition operator. But in the question they have noting more than I had above

Comment: It's fine. As soon as you know the spectral theorem for self-adjoint operators, my proof works in any dimension.

Answer (score 2):

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T$ a semi-positive linear operator.

Suppose $T$ is an isometry. Recall that all self-adjoint linear operators are diagonalizable. Hence, we are left to prove that 1 is the only eigenvalue of $T$. Let $v\in H$ be an eigenvector to the eigenvalue $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, then holds

$$ 0\neq \langle v, v \rangle \stackrel{\text{$T$ isometry}}{=} \langle T(v), T(v) \rangle = \lambda^2 \langle v, v \rangle. $$

Hence, $\lambda \in \{\pm 1\}$. But $T$ is semi-posivite, hence

$$ 0  \leq \langle T(v), v \rangle = \lambda \underbrace{\langle v, v \rangle}_{\geq 0}.$$

Thus, $T$ has only 1 as eigenvalue and is diagonalizable and therefore $T=I$. The other direction is trivial.